# Problem with int in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, singleton, nsinteger

```
singelton.categoryId = (int)[categories.categoriesId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%d", singelton.categoryId);
```

`singelton.categoryId` is from type `int`.
But when I try to print it number is random, but if I do this `NSLog(@"%@", singelton.categoryId);` the printed value is right.
I need to print it with `%d`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **intValue** method to get the integer representation of a *NSString/NSNumber*. Try,

```
singelton.categoryId = [[categories.categoriesId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the array returns you an NSNumber. So try this out.

```
int catId = [ ((NSNumber*) [categories.categoriesId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ) intValue];
NSLog(@"%d, catId )
```

Comment: you're awesome.  no one else "gets" the question.

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [singelton.categoryId intValue]);
```

Comment: He writes that `singleton.categoryID` is an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Try do do this in this way:

```
singelton.categoryId = [[categories.categoriesId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]
```

It's because you can't store ints in array - they must be `NSNumbers`.

Answer (score 1):

The category ID as returned by `objectAtIndex:` is an object, most probably an `NSNumber`. By casting it to `int` you get the address of the object, not the numeric value stored in it. The correct code would be something like this:

```
singleton.categoryID = [[… objectAtIndex:…] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way that's coming from an `int` primitive type when it's a proper object (assuming that `objectAtIndex` behaves here as elsewhere in Objective-C--i.e., it's not your own method.  So, you'll need to ask for the `intValue`:

`[[categories.categoriesId objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]`

if it is an available method.  What class is `categoriesID`?